# CMD - Need something like %~dp0 which is space friendly

Tags: windows, command-line

> Info you don't really need - Hi All, Looking for some help with a CMD app to make life easy at work
>   for me and a bunch of other guys. We will be moving the folder containing the app around from place to place and to make it run a parameter is needed which has its current location. Real story begins below - Thanks for your help. :)

I am wanting a parameter which is space friendly, so I can use it for further calls.

Works like this, I have an Install.cmd, which does the following.

```
echo off
set a= properties.txt
del %a%
echo %~dp0 >> %a%
```

properties.txt then looks like this.

```
E:\Users\USER\Google Drive\_ACP\
```

ApplicationStart.cmd does the following.

```
(Set /p ROOT=
) <properties.txt
CALL %ROOT%\data\TOOLS\INIT.CMD
```

Trouble is this. The path which is added to the properties.txt is

```
E:\Users\USER\Google Drive\_ACP\
```

and for the call to work it needs to be (To accommodate the space in Google Drive)

```
E:\Users\USER\"Google Drive"\_ACP\
```

Manually editing the file to look like the above makes my app work fine.

Is their an alternative to `%~dp0` which is folder space friendly? 
I have googled till I cant google no more. :)

Comment: This is a stackoverflow question. You can ask the question on our stackoverflow page and get better results. Since you are new here, I suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the variable when it is being expanded:

```
call "%ROOT%\data\tools\init.cmd"
```

Or use a more sensible language such as PowerShell, JScript, VBScript (Windows comes with runtimes for all three), or maybe C#.